# How do I use variables inside a stringified key in a nested dict?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, data-structures

I have a default message body which is to be used to send as a post request.
Below is my message body : -

```
msg_body = {
    "deviceId": "36330586",
    "Command": {
        "text": "{\"2\":{\"21\":\"agenda\",\"22\":\"Serial\",\"31\":\"On\",\"32\":\"On\",\"33\":\"Off\",\"34\":\"Off\",\"41\":\"127\",\"51\":\"0:21\",\"61\":\"5:21\",\"71\":\"10\",\"81\":\"10\",\"91\":\"0\",\"101\":\"0\",\"111\":\"false\"}}"
    },
    "description": "Execute command 2"
}
```

I'm calling an api to fetch the values which I need to pass using variables inside `text`.
For example the `text` contains keys `21 22 31 32` and so on.... I want to use variables for each of the values in `text` so that I can pass the values which I get from the api.
Therefore for example :

```
\"21\":\"agenda\",\"22\":\"Serial\",\"31\":\"On\"....
```

Instead of agenda I want to use a variable mode, for Serial I want to pass the value using variable serial_val and so on...

This message body will be then used for making post request :

```py
r2 = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(msg_body), headers=headers)
```

Comment: use `json` module to convert string into json object with `json_obj = json.loads(msg_body)`, then you can do whatever you want with obj. For example `json_job["Command"]["text"]["22"]= serial_val`

Comment: Throws ```raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict```

Comment: What is a "stringified key" exactly? How is it done?

Comment: @martineau from that I mean the key `text` is nested dict which is wrapped within double quotes.

Comment: Python support something called "[f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)" where you can define string values using the expressions embedded in the string between `{}` characters. i.e. `key = f"{serial_val}"` which I think could do what you need (although I am not sure I understand your question)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python inbuilt `json` module to serialize and deserialize json objects. You example is a dict with serialized nested `text` key which you can deserialize and convert to json object.

First we deserialize the text part because that seems to be the most important part for you

```
import json

msg_body = {
"deviceId": "36330586",
"Command": {
    "text": "{\"2\":{\"21\":\"agenda\",\"22\":\"Serial\",\"31\":\"On\",\"32\":\"On\",\"33\":\"Off\",\"34\":\"Off\",\"41\":\"127\",\"51\":\"0:21\",\"61\":\"5:21\",\"71\":\"10\",\"81\":\"10\",\"91\":\"0\",\"101\":\"0\",\"111\":\"false\"}}"
},
"description": "Execute command 2"
}

text_obj = json.loads(msg_body["Command"]["text"])
```

then we update values like you mentioned

```
text_obj["2"]["22"] = "serial_val" # was "Serial" before
text_obj["2"][<other_key>] = <other value>
```

then we serialize the `text_obj` and update value in `msg_body`

```
msg_body["Command"]["text"] = json.dumps(text_obj)
print(msg_body)
```

now you can use `msg_body` with updated value to make web request.

Comment: I know it's a silly question but I noticed that inside `text` you've changed double quotes to single quotes. Will it make any difference if I use the logic given by you using the exact same msg_body content which I've given in the question?

Comment: it should not, my vs-code did it automatically. I see no reason why this shouldnt work.

Comment: Okay, let me try this solution and get back with the results.

Comment: I'm getting following as the output after print(msg_body) : ```{'deviceId': '19035813', 'Command': {'text': '{"2": {"21": "agenda", "22": "Serial", "31": "On", "32": "On", "33": "On", "34": "Off", "41": "127", "51": "00:40", "61": "19:40", "71": "10", "81": "10", "91": "10", "101": "0", "111": "false"}}'}, 'description': 'Execute command 2'}``` This json is not correct.

Comment: nevermind, json.dumps(msg_body) works

Comment: if it helped you, could you please mark this as an answer?